# Service Fabric Cluster Node gone down suddenly

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have created a 5 node azure service fabric and deployed application on it many times, however one of node on my service fabric has suddenly gone down and is in error state , while the remaining  nodes are active. I've tried manually activating the node through cluster explorer , but nothing happens. I've also tried restarting the node, neither of which has helped.

Is there anyway to force this node back online, or am I going to have to delete the cluster and start again ?

Comment: If this is a Windows cluster, can you RDP to the node and check the event viewer for errors? Can you run PS `Get-ServiceFabricNodeHealth` to see a node health report?

Comment: I checked bu since the node is down I am unable to do RDP .

Comment: So is the VM down entirely? What is the output of Get-ServiceFabricNodeHealth?